# How to set a test case variable in property transfer for xpath?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am having an issue with property transfer and test case variable in soap UI.

Basically in my property transfers I want to pull out a value from a soap request response step, but I want the some values to be picked out from a test case property like so:

```
declare namespace T='http://test.com'

//T:Testxml/T:NextLevel/T:FinalLevel[@date='${#TestCase#testDate}']/@price
```

However it doesn't like this as it spits out [null] but when I replace the variable to a hard coded date (same value as in the test case property), then it works.

My question is how can I pass through a test case variable in this scenario?

Comment: What does "it doesn't like this" mean? Please have a read through [mcve].

Comment: I meant it displays [null] but it should t do because the hard coded equivalent gives out a price

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43889195/2986279 this answer can help and also you can ignore property transfer and use a groovy instead as listed in the comment there